# Is "today's" grammatical as a singular possessive?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

Is the following correct?

> Today's easy to use models can come in handy for a variety of purposes.

Is *today's* correct as a singular possessive?

Comment: It's certainly correct.  When I googled "today's", I got 759 million hits.  What's the question, exactly?

Comment: Please support our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Comment: Please never just ask “Is this correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct, but you need hyphens:

> Today's easy-to-use models can come in handy for a variety of purposes.